# Not displaying blog posts formatted in Github as observed locally

Tags: jekyll

What a likely cause would it be if my blog builds just fine locally but in GitHub? Once it is in GitHub nav bar does not display nor do post styles are applied; intriguingly, this strange behavior only affects post pages.

My blog is set [here](http://danielmarcelino.github.io) and [here](https://github.com/danielmarcelino/danielmarcelino.github.io) is its repository.
The strange behavior is visible whenever one clicks on a blog post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're gonna need to make sure you have this:

`_config.yml`:

```
highlighter: rouge
markdown: kramdown
kramdown:
  input: GFM

gems:
  - jekyll-paginate
  # other gems
```

`Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'github-pages'
gem 'jekyll-paginate'
# other gems
```

Then, open the terminal at your project's location and run:

`bundle update` => will update all your gems

`bundle install` => will generate a new `Gemfile.lock` including all gems and their dependencies

`bundle exec jekyll serve` => will serve Jekyll via Bundler

***Why?***, you may ask. Jekyll has a new version 3, and [GitHub Pages followed the upgrade](https://github.com/blog/2100-github-pages-now-faster-and-simpler-with-jekyll-3-0). The default markdown in now `kramdown` and the default highlighter is now `rouge`. Any doubts, check it [here](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/upgrading/2-to-3/).

---

**ALSO:**

Your blog posts don't have links for your stylesheets found in the `index.html` head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/index.css" />
```

Probably something wrong with your `includes`.

Comment: It is still not working, but then you guys point me why it stopped working.

Comment: I'll give a better look into your repo and get back to you later, ok?

Comment: Including head.html in post layout = calling css from inside html body. Not so tidy.

Comment: Ooops! Sorry! I didn't realise that! I'll take a look later and correct the answer.

Comment: Well, I've checked out how have you proceeded and everything seems to be up and running, right? The only thing I believe you have forgotten is removing `{% include head.html %}` from the `_layouts/post.html`.  So I don't see any reason to develop a new way of making things work. I'll edit my answer to taking the last part out of it. Thanks for your support and sorry about the mistake. All the best for you!

Answer (score 1):

Let's call it the **Jekyll 3 shake**

Your blog build ok locally because your still working with `github-pages version 40` and `jekyll version 2.4.0`.

```
bundle update
bundle exec jekyll build
```

And it will break on posts.

From your workflow `post -> post layout -> base layout that includes head.html`

In **jekyll 2.4.0** : from head you see `page.layout = base` and then you see `base` layout front matter variables.
In **jekyll 3.0.3** : from head you see `page.layout = post` and then you **can't** see `base` layout front matter variables.

The idea can be to move base's front matter variables to `_config.yml` :

```
common-css:
  - "/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  - "/css/main.css"
common-ext-css:
  - "//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
...
```

And to get those variables in `_includes/head.html`

```
{% if site.common-ext-css %}
  {% for css in site.common-ext-css %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ css }}" />
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Same for js files.

Note : upgrading to Jekyll 3.x implies that you add

```
gems: [jekyll-paginate]
```

to your `_config.yml` file.

Comment: Thanks for the workflow, it still not working after after updating to jekyll 3.0.3  and gems, but I will figure out more carefully later.

Comment: Your answer solved the issue as the answer of @Virtua Creative; I'll accept her answer instead once my policy of tie breaking is to favor people with lower scores as incentive, but I'll give you +1. Thank you.

Comment: A agree with your tie break policy, but I gave you the only working answer, so there is no tie-break.

Comment: Just a quick tip: if he runs `bundle exec jekyll build` after `bundle update` he will be working with [Jekyll 3.1.1](https://rubygems.org/gems/jekyll/), its last version. But GH Pages is using [Jekyll 3.0.2](https://github.com/github/pages-gem#list-dependency-versions), so he needs a `Gemfile` with `gem 'github-pages'`
and `gem 'jekyll-paginate'` in order to having the same configuration, otherwise his builds (local and on GH) will be completely different.

Comment: `git clone git@github.com:danielmarcelino/danielmarcelino.github.io.git` then `cd danielmarcelino.github.io` then `bundle update` then `bundle exec jekyll -v` =====>>>>> `jekyll 3.0.3` that's what I get. `bundle show github-pages` ====> `/.rbenv/versions/2.1.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/github-pages-48` And I give up here.